# Programming FPGA with AVR Programmer instead of USB Blaster

Tags: fpga, avr, intel-fpga, jtag, flashing

I bought a MAX 10 FPGA 10M08 Dev Board and is has a JTAG on it that says to program with a Altera USB Blaster. Being impatient and all can I use my AVR Programmer and connect, assuming target power is used like so?

```
AVR => JTAG
===========
SCK  -> TCK
MISO -> TDO
REST -> TMS
MOSI -> TDI
```

I am guessing the clock speeds here sck to tck may be the biggest issue?

Answer (score 0):

JTAG != AVR ISP

Not only is JTAG *completely* different from Atmel's AVR ISP, even if you had an Atmel JTAG programmer, it's very unlikely it would work with the Altera FPGA. Despite JTAG being a common "standard", JTAG programmers/devices from different vendors do not necessarily work together, often because the vendor specific tools do not like non-vendor programmers.

Comment: The vendor specific tools often include the ability to load SVF or even STAPL, and most JTAG adapters are supported by vendor independent tools such as UrJTAG or OpenOCD. That said, an AVR programmer is still likely to implement too much of the protocol to be usable for JTAG; simple bitbanging adaptors can be adaptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any old Raspberry Pi laying around, you can use that for JTAG instead - the hardware natively supports it.